# back color Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to paint a red-green texture in Unity, but it's displayed all in yellow. Why? Please help!

```
    GameObject ekranprawy = GameObject.Find("ekranprawy");
    MeshRenderer rr = ekranprawy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    int size = 128;
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(size, size, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
        { 
            if(y > (size / 2))
                tex.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
            else
                tex.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(0,255, 0, 255));
        }
    }
    tex.Apply(); //You need to Apply so that the new texture is sent to the GPU
    rr.material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the color of the Material is White. Use this:

```
    rr.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.white);
```

Comment: You could also change the color of the material from the Editor.